# How to progress with feature maps

Tags: conv-neural-network

The amount of half-baked material on cnn-topics is staggering.

At the moment i struggle with how to progress with the extracted feature maps of an image. Lets say i have 3 of them, extracted from a 32x32 image. The next step is to apply kernels to them, too.

Do i use the same kernels i used on the original image?
If not, am i generating new kernels and apply them to every feature map?
Or do i use completely different kernels for each individual feature map?

Comment: What's a feature map?  I'm familiar with CNNs, but I don't know that term.

Answer (score 0):

You use different kernels for each feature map. At each stage you are trying to extract different features from an image (you can view them as more high-level features each consecutive time).

Also keep in mind, that you may have various depth of feature map after convolutions, which makes it impossible to use the same kernel multiple times.

So to sum up, you initialize separate kernel for each feature map. You should initialize them not to be the same (e.g. not all on 0). Then you apply learning algorithm on each kernel, and they change "independently".